# The clerk concerned VS the concerned clerk

Tags: meaning-in-context, indian-english, semantics

> 1. I want to meet the concerned  clerk
> 2. I want to meet  the  clerk concerned

According  the grammar book by  David  Green  the first sentence means **I want to meet the clerk  who  is  tense  or  worried**

The  second  sentence  means   **I want  to meet  the  clerk who is incharge of the section**.

Most  of  the nonnative  speakers  I know  say  **I want  to meet the  concerned  clerk**.

Is  there really  difference between  the  two  sentences?

Comment: @James K.Thank you for the prompt and the correct answer.I have accepted and upvoted your answer.I know the answer but I want to know from a native scholar like you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David Green is correct.

The first "concerned" is an adjective describing the clerk. When applied to a human the adjective means "worried".

The second concerned is part of a relative clause

> the clerk (who is) concerned (with this matter)

this is from the verb "to concern" which means "to be relevant to"

The meanings of the two sentences are completely different.  The first sentence would hardly ever be used. Usually you don't want to see a worried clerk.